# django - once extended block gets overridden

Tags: python, django

I am learning with django 2.0, in python 3.6, on windows. I would like to create page with three different blocks, and therefore, this can be seen in the base.html:

`base.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='menu'>{% block menu %} start menu {% endblock menu %}</div>
    <div class="content">{% block content %} start content {% endblock content %}</div>
    <div class="buttons">{% block buttons %} start buttons {% endblock buttons %}</div> 
</body>

</html>
```

And this is, how my urls.py looks like:

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.MenuView.as_view(), name='menu'),
    path('folder<pk>/', views.FolderView.as_view(), name='folder'),
    path('picture<int:picture_id>/', views.picture, name='picture_url')
]
```

When I come to localhost:8000/check_images, I call menu view, which should extend base.html.

In the first block, I would like to display menu bar, which shows all folders. I would like to have this bar visible everywhere, on every page.
This is called via following view:

`views.py`

```
class MenuView(generic.ListView):
    model = Folder
    template_name = 'check_images/menu.html'
    context_object_name = 'folders'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.all()
```

which renders into check_image/menu.html:

`menu.html`

```
{% extends "check_images/base.html" %}
{% block menu %}
    {% for folder in folders %}
        <a href="{% url 'folder' folder.id %}">{{ folder.id }} -- {{ folder.name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock menu %}
```

Up till now, everything works as intended. The menu loads, when I come to the page, and the base.html is extended.

However, whenever I click on any menu item, I would like the menu to stay, and render only the block below the menu - content and buttons, as I tried to code here. 
But the menu does not stay, so again only 'start menu' string, hardcoded in base.html is shown.

`views.py`

```
class FolderView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Folder
    template_name = 'check_images/folder.html'
```

`folder.html`

```
{% extends "check_images/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {{ object.picture_set.all.0 }}
{% endblock content %}
{% block buttons %} 
    {% if object.picture_set.all.1 %}
    <a href="{% url 'picture_url' object.picture_set.all.1.id %}"> Next </a>
    {% else %}
    nada
    {% endif %}
{% endblock buttons %}
```

So how should I extend already extended base.html? Why is the `{% block menu %}` overridden again? How should I prevent it, and what is the 'correct' way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the block menu overriden as you say?
Quite simple - you just did not define this block in your `folder.html` template, so Django used the default line being `start menu`.

You only specified `{% block menu %}` in the `menu.html` template, it won't get 'carried over' anywhere else.

How you might want to fix this:
first include `menu.html` in the templates, where you would like the menu to display all the folders in `folders.html`.

```
{% extends "check_images/base.html" %}
{% include 'check_images/menu.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {{ object.picture_set.all.0 }}
{% endblock content %}
{% block buttons %} 
    {% if object.picture_set.all.1 %}
    <a href="{% url 'picture_url' object.picture_set.all.1.id %}"> Next </a>
    {% else %}
    nada
    {% endif %}
{% endblock buttons %}
```

If you want it to display that menu on all templates extending base.html then you might want to move that for loop from `menu.html` there so you dont have to include it everywhere, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='menu'>   {% for folder in folders %}
        <a href="{% url 'folder' folder.id %}">{{ folder.id }} -- {{ folder.name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}{% block menu %}  my menu {% endblock menu %}</div>
    <div class="content">{% block content %} start content {% endblock content %}</div>
    <div class="buttons">{% block buttons %} start buttons {% endblock buttons %}</div> 
</body>

</html>
```

Then add a bit of code to the view, so django knows what folders are.

```
class FolderView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Folder
    template_name = 'check_images/folder.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(FolderView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['folders'] = Folder.objects.all()
        return context
```

The downside is that you have to specify what 'folders' are in every view that uses base.html.

EDIT: If you don't want to specify it everyhwhere, making folders available globaly to templates, do this:

Open your `settings.py` and find TEMPLATES, it might look like so

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': '...',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

then add `'your_app.context_processors.folders_menu'` to it, like so:
(remember to change 'your_app' to the name of your_app :)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': '...',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'your_app.context_processors.folders_menu',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Create a file `context_processors.py` inside your app directory and write there:

```
def folders_menu(request):
    from your_app.models import Folder
    return {'folders': Folder.objects.all()}
```

Now you can just put that for-loop with folders in your `base.html` and it will work everywhere without overwriting that `get_context_data()` method - you may delete that part of the code.

Comment: thanks for explanation, this explains all my pain. I was actually trying to specify the `folders` only once (to keep the code as clean as possible), could you outline shortly the correct solution to that?

Comment: Make your own context processor :D

 I'll edit my answer in a second.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the include directive instead of block for your menu.
The folder.html file would look like this

```
    {% extends "check_images/base.html" %}
     <div class='menu'>{% include 'check_images/menu.html' %}</div>
    {% block content %}
    {{ object.picture_set.all.0 }}
    {% endblock content %}
    {% block buttons %} 
    {% if object.picture_set.all.1 %}
    <a href="{% url 'picture_url' object.picture_set.all.1.id %}">     Next </a>
     {% else %}
    nada
    {% endif %}
    {% endblock buttons %}
```

Then your menu file would be

```
{% for folder in folders %}
<a href="{% url 'folder' folder.id %}">{{ folder.id }} -- {{  folder.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Then you can always include or not include the menu file on any template you don't need it e.g your homepage, about page etc.

Comment: thanks, I believe this would solve my problem, however then I would have to call menu on every page - something I want to avoid

Answer (score 1):

If i understand well you think that if you extend base.html once and then write some code in block so it will be saved for every other html file where you extend base.html right?

It's not working like that. Every time you call another html file and extend base.html, it loads only this what is coded in base.html.

You cannot extend menu.html becouse it's getting some data to show from view. In my opinion you have to make one view and then if some folder is clicked you tell your view that it should now show blocks content and buttons for specific folder.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was thinking. Could you please elaborate on how to 'make one view and then if some folder is clicked you tell your view that it should now show blocks content and buttons for specific folder.' ?

Comment: You can make a variable in your view called folder which at start is defined to an empty string. And then you can make a url parameter with id of clicked folder: '/ckeck_images/?folder=1' and then in your view, you check if you get some parameter in url, if there is some parameter and parameter it's an integer, you find specific folder and you give your variable 'folder' value of this folder. And then in template you just check if variable 'folder' which you send to template is equal empty string you render only menu, if not you can render everythink.

Comment: Ofc you make an url with parameter when folder is clicked